# Is there a way to compare local [non-git] file tree directly to a remote git repo using a git/console command?

Tags: git, diff

So my local file tree is just a file tree no git repo.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to compare the full directory to a remote git repo while not creating a git repository in the local directory/machine?

'Easy' means no copying full folder trees over a clone here. As that's the only solution I could think of already, but that seems like a drag for something like this.

Comment: There is not. `git` really only knows about managing local repositories.  The only thing it can do with a remote repository is "send changes" or "receive changes".

Comment: In *nix you often have the tool `diff` which works similar to `git diff` (just more general and on files/directories than commits/working tree). That would do it. Does your question for console command include this?

Comment: @LinFelix I ended up creating a separate clone en checking out the correct commit to compare the local folder with and afterwards running the `diff` command to compare both directories. Which seemed to work fine. But I was hoping for some magic git function I guess. Never wrong to dream ;)

Comment: @TommyBravo Theoretically if you have the same commit (when comparing only one branch in each repository) you know that both repolsitories are identically, because if any single commit content was different the hash would be different and then each child commit would be different as well, because it has a different parent.

Comment: @LinFelix Yes I know, but I was comparing to see/find the local changes in an 'export' of a certain commit (so the local folder was no git repo strictly speaking). I was already sure there were some changes made inside the folder but I wasn't sure in which files and which lines exactly.

Comment: Are you using GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a solution:

```
for i in $(find -type f );
do
diff $i <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>/master/$(echo $i | cut -c 3-))
done
```

This command will compare your local files with the GitHub repository `<user_name>/<repo_name>`.

For Gitlab

```
for i in $(find -type f );
do
diff $i <(curl -s https://<gitlab_instance>/<project_name>/<repo_name>/raw/master/.gitlab/$(echo $i | cut -c 3-))
done
```

This command will compare your local files with the  `<project_name>/<repo_name>`.

If you are using a private repo then you can modify the `curl` command accordingly and give if your access token or a password. For more information see [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I use an "on premise" gitlab instance instead of github.

Comment: This probably means I'll have to login to get the file from gitlab instead and that might not be so simple from the command line ;)

Comment: Well, I hope this now answers your question?